# Excel text wrapping no longer centres text below by using the space bar

Tags: microsoft-excel

For the past 10 years, in all of my Excel documents, if I want the text in a cell to go onto the line below (Text wrapping in same cell) I would add an extra few spaces in the space bar - or a lot of spaces - and the next word would go into the line below. At the time, I didn't know about 'Alt'+'Enter' and I've just always done it out of habit.

I've just printed a document to PDF and all is fine. Then, I opened the Excel document again as I noticed a typo and all the text wrapping was no longer neat and even. I've opened about 20 files to check and ALL my Excel documents are like this. I cannot figure out why and it's too much to go through everything - as I have hundreds - and format it all again, even using 'Alt'+'Enter'.  If I double click in the cell as if to edit the typing then it goes correct and looks ok, but as soon as I click back out of that cell it's got big spaces in and the line below is no longer centred. I now have to press the exact amount of spaces needed and keep looking at print preview to make sure it's correct. It used to just have lots of spaces and automatically centre the text below.

Does anyone know what on earth I've done?  Attached is a photo of what I mean.

[image: example pic]

Comment: Have you changed your default printer to a PDF printer? I know of a bug where a pdf printer has different margins, breaking strange layout like this.

Comment: Yes my default printer is PDF, though it always has been as i only every want then in PDF.  I've just tried changing it to another couple but still looks the same,  its very strange as i've done nothing that i know of.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Excel does not allow line formatting the way you want, so your use of spaces will eneviitably come to haunt you in some way or another. There are some plugins that allow HTML or rich text, but this has other drawbacks, especially when you are outside the plugin installation. So best to live with the limitations, or use a text field for headers.

Comment: This is quite strange. I tried to duplicate your example. I can get a word to drop down onto line 2 by adding spaces (with wrapping on) but no amount of spaces will move the first word on line 2 forward - as if any more spaces just automatically jumps back to line 1.  I.e. I am unable to place spaces before "to go on another line" in line 2 of your example. Mine just looks like yours did originally. The only way to add spaces before a word on a new line is to add a ALT+enter. If you open your file on another computer, does it display correctly? And if you save it first on you current pc?

Comment: Did you check the TEXT alignment?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I initially tried to change printer from default PDF as LPChip suggested and it showed nothing changing, i've come to work this morning, opened my PFMEA document and it's all back to normal, i've checked 20 others and all ok now, so it must have been some glitch in the printer i had chosen, i'm still PDF but changing it to something else then back seems to have fixed it. Going forward i'll start using the ALT+Enter on all new documents so this won't happen again.  It was very strange as every excel i opened was the same.  Thank you everyone appreciate your comments.